Count and Grouping by changes in a value
I have the following data
num = c(4, 3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 3)
v1 =  c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)

I would like to create a NEW column that counts the instances that include the same value in V1, and increase by 1 when a change in value in the same column occurs, and get an output like this (trial)...
num =    c(4, 3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 3)
v1  =    c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)
trial =  c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)

Ultimately I would like to create a column that cumsums the values in the column 'num' that are in the same trial, like this
num =  c(4, 3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 3)
v1 =   c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)
trial =c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)
cumsum=c(4, 7, 13, 1, 2, 5, 8)

I am hoping to use 'mutate' or something else that will add a new column to this existing data frame and not create a different summary table....

With library(dplyr) you can use the consecutive_id function: your_data |> mutate(trial = consecutive_id(v1)) |> mutate(cumsum = cumsum(num), .by = trial)
